# How do I enable automatic email for SVN post-commits for a SVN+SSH repo in the local network?

Tags: svn, email, hook

We have a server whose SVN repos are accessible either via SVN+SSH or SAMBA. I already created:

- a shell script to send email (it works when executed by itself),
- a shell script based on the `post-commit.tmpl` in `<repo path>/hooks/` which I named `post-commit` (executable by all)

I even added a `touch` command within each script just so I can determine that a script actually ran.

Unfortunately, it turns out that the `post-commit` script itself doesn't execute.  I'm not sure if it's the setup, being SVN+SSH.  I checked the server and there is no running `svnserve` process (not sure if this is relevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relevant. Basically, you're accessing the repo using the filt: protocol, which directly accesses the repository filesystem. That is not recommended.

You want to run svnserve and access the repo through it, using the svn: protocol (or use apache and use the http protocol). The server components are the pieces that maintain transactional integrity of your repo, and also run the hook scripts.

The direct file access methods are really only there for administrative tools to use.